# How to avoid overfitting (while training a model and predicting) in a dataset that is basically overfitted?

Tags: classification, data-transformation, overfitting, multilabel

I need to solve a multi-label classification problem where the dataset itself is the definition of overfitting, in the sense that some labels appear a lot (almost 50% frequency), some rarely appear, some have a lot of empty values (almost 90% frequency) which are meaningful considering the business rule, etc.

I trained a Transformer model and the loss is low over time, the F1 score is 1, the LRAP is .99%, but the classification results are insanely bad. All the attributes are categorical.

I tried to 'fix' the empty values, but since they have a meaning in the business rule that is not a good preprocessing. Besides this, I tried to apply the most frequent metric, which will 'reduce' the overfitting in a side and increase the bias in another.

Any ideas if is it even possible to solve and if yes, how?

Comment: **1.** What does it mean that some labels have a lot of empty values? **2.** How can classification results be insanely when F1 score is 1? How do you measure the goodness of classification results? **3.** What do you mean by *apply the most frequent metric*?

Comment: 1. I have the labels A, B, and C, for label A which is categorical I have 0 or 1, zero means that the label is not present for the register X and 1 means that the label is present for the register X, just the labels are binarized, the input sentences are sent as a text to the model

Comment: 2. Cause I have a lot of registers that has the label A and just a few that has the other classes (B and C), even if I shuffle the data the registers that are the minority has no impact on the final result, cause I'm dealing with binary labels I need to use sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer to compute the F1, which I'm treating as a side matric, i.e just seeing it but considering the LRAP (ranking-based average precision) and loss, does it make sense for you?

Comment: 3. I have a lot of missing values, which I explained above, to place some values on the missing fields I tried sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer with the metric 'most frequent value' to validate if doing this the prediction would not be 'overfitted', but no changes

Comment: Notes: 1. Label vs classes is important here, 2. I have only two features to predict N labels 3. None of the features and labels are standardized, I preprocessed them to clean and all that basic, but crucial,  things but I can't drastically change the structure cause the model needs to have it as a sentence to consider the orthographic rules 4. In the sentences, there are financial notations and the idiom is not English